# Is there a heaven in the Top Cow Universe?

Tags: comics, top-cow-universe

In the Angelus miniseries, when Danielle Baptiste is escorted by Sabine to the 'domain of light,' she asks, "Is this heaven?"  Sabrine replies, "There is no heaven."  Rather, the 'domain of light' is the home for the Angelus warriors, and the Angelus herself (typically).

It's pretty clear that there is a Hell - Jackie Estacado goes there briefly before returning to Earth via Tom Judge's powers.  Hell is shown again in the Angelus miniseries, when Sabine sends some of the Angelus warriors to retrieve the Wheel of Shadows (Tom Judge is again featured).

Given that Sabine is fairly unreliable given her hostility to Danielle, is there ever a Heaven of any kind presented or referenced to in the Top Cow universe?

Comment: Hell of a title (no pun intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While chatting with my good friend Ron Marz (creator and coordinator of the Top Cow Universe), I found time to ask your question.

The answer is a definitive "**no**"; no literal heaven has ever been seen within the series to date

---

[image]

---

I noted to him that this doesn't close the door to it being seen in a *later* edition but as yet, he's declined to take the bait.